# Autoit run a function if key pressed three times in a limited amount of time

Tags: windows, button, keyboard, autoit

I have this code so far:

```
#include <Misc.au3>
While True
    If _IsPressed(57) Then
        Sleep(100)
        If Not _IsPressed(57) Then
            Sleep(100)
            If _IsPressed(57) Then
                Sleep(100)
                If Not _IsPressed(57) Then
                    Sleep(100)
                    If _IsPressed(57) Then
                        Sleep(100)
                        If Not _IsPressed(57) Then
                            up()
                        EndIf
                    EndIf
                EndIf
            EndIf
        EndIf
    EndIf
WEnd

Func up()
   Send("{w down}")
   Sleep(10000)
   Send("{w up}")
   Sleep(500)
EndFunc
```

The problem is that it will only work some times and it is temperamental. Does any one know how I could make it work every time rather than just some times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for.

```
HotKeySet("a", "pressed")
Dim $i = 0, $PushTime = 1000

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd

Func pressed()
    $i += 1
    Sleep($PushTime)
    Switch $i
        Case 1
            put(1)
        Case 2
            put(2)
        Case 3
            put(3)
        Case 4
            Exit (0)
    EndSwitch
    $i = 0
EndFunc   ;==>pressed

Func put($y)
    MsgBox(0, "Func called: ", "Nr: " & $y)
EndFunc   ;==>put
```